# Потеря данных при записи файла File.WriteAllLines

Tags: c#

Есть файл, в котором находятся данные `data1`, полное имя с адресом в переменной `FullFileName`.
Я записываю новые данные в данный файл `File.WriteAllLines(FullFileName, data2);`
Если во время выполнения записи произойдет ошибка, ну к примеру закончилось место на носителе, то что произойдет? Файл будет пустой, в нем останутся данные `data1`, или часть данных `data2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Файл будет пустой, в нем останутся данные data1, или часть данных data2?

Вообще, из-за ошибки записи может произойти и то, и другое и третье:

- Если файл не получится открыть, то содержимое не изменится.
- Если файл получится открыть и затереть, но при этом при первой записи произойдет ошибка — файл будет пустой.
- Если запись оборвется посередине, то в файле останется часть новых данных.

Если ошибка возникнет именно из-за нехватки места на носителе, то наиболее вероятен последний вариант, т.к. метод начнет записывать данные в файл, просто не сможет закончить.

Вот пример кода, который симулирует все три варианта развития событий:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //записываем три файла с одинаковым текстом
        File.WriteAllText("unchanged", "initial");
        File.WriteAllText("empty", "initial");
        File.WriteAllText("partial", "initial");

        //симулируем ошибки
        //один файл занимаем другим потоком (в реальности может быть другой процесс)
        //запись оборвется при попытке открытия
        var unchangedLock = new FileStream("unchanged", FileMode.Open);
        //в другом блокируем часть файла
        //запись оборвется при попытке записи
        var emptyLock = new FileStream("empty", FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        emptyLock.Lock(1, 1);

        //запускаем потоки для перезаписи файлов
        var unchangedThread = CreateWriteThread("unchanged");
        var emptyThread = CreateWriteThread("empty");
        var partialThread = CreateWriteThread("partial");

        //дожидаемся завершения записи
        unchangedThread.Join();
        emptyThread.Join();
        //запись третьего файла обрывается посередине
        //по каким-то причинам, например, из-за нехватки места на диске
        partialThread.Abort();

        //освобождаем файлы чтобы прочитать
        unchangedLock.Close();
        emptyLock.Close();

        //выводим первые строки после записи
        //первый файл не изменился
        Console.WriteLine("Unchanged: " + File.ReadLines("unchanged").FirstOrDefault());
        //второй стал пустым
        Console.WriteLine("Empty: " + File.ReadLines("empty").FirstOrDefault());
        //третий перезаписан, но не до конца
        Console.WriteLine("Partial: " + File.ReadLines("partial").FirstOrDefault());

        Console.Read();
    }

    static Thread CreateWriteThread(string filename)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(filename, Enumerable.Repeat("new line", 1000000));
            }
            catch{/*nobody cares*/}
        });
        thread.Start();
        return thread;
    }
}
```

Он выводит:

```
Unchanged: initial
Empty:
Partial: new line
```

Если нужна защита от ошибок при записи файла, т.е. чтобы было два варианта: либо файл записался полностью, либо не изменился, то попробуйте записать данные во временный файл, и поменять файлы местами. При этом все равно сохраняется возможность возникновения ошибок, но по крайней мере есть вариант для отката и исключается сценарий с частичной записью данных. Посмотрите [How to do atomic writes in a file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/12/28/how-to-do-atomic-writes-in-a-file/).

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезный и развернутый ответ!

Comment: @Андрей Пожалуйста! Не забудьте [отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Слева от ответа должна быть серая галка. Нажмите на нее.